# What is the difference between "when" and "in doing"?

Tags: conjunctions, gerunds

I know that the phrase "in doing something" has a meaning similar to the conjunction "when", but I don't know their difference.  For example, which of the following sounds natural?:

> 1. I always wear rubber gloves **when washing** dishes to protect my hands.
> 2. I always wear rubber gloves **in washing** dishes to protect my hands.

Comment: Where did you learn such a strange rule? **In doing** roughly means **when doing** but not just **when** and not always the other way around. _Methods and skills used in doing something, take turns in doing something, be successful in doing something, be wary in doing something_ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Use **in** when you want to express the idea "by virtue of" or "as a result of":

> In submitting your application early you may improve your chances of being accepted into the program if the school has so-called "rolling admissions".

or

> In calling him a liar publicly in print you have put your life in danger.
>
> You have put your life in danger in calling him a liar publicly in print.

There is nothing *temporal* about that meaning; rather *instrumentality* is the underlying idea. You could change **in** there to **by**.

Use **when** when you want to express the idea of "whenever" or "while".

> Wear goggles when working with caustic chemicals.
>
> Wear goggles in working with caustic chemicals. <sup>ungrammatical</sup>

There are some activities where **in** with the ing-form of the verb casts the activity as a *manner of doing*, and in those cases **in** would be idiomatic:

> Take care in how you mix these volatile chemicals.
>
> Take care in mixing these volatile chemicals.
>
> Take care in crossing the busy street.

There the meaning is not "whenever" or "while" but "in your manner of doing the thing" or "in how you do the thing".  With **in** the focus is not on the  *occasion* of the doing but on the doing *per se*, on the activity itself.

Comment: A question arises whether **in** might be dropped altogether with no loss for the meaning: _Submitting your application early you may improve...Calling him a liar publicly....Wear goggles working with caustic....Take care mixing these volatile....Take care crossing the busy...._? "Take care in mixing" vs "take care mixing" = 97:14300 in Google.

Comment: I don't think there's *zero* loss of meaning.  It might approach zero, but doesn't get there.  *He put out the fire pissing on it.*

Comment: I'd say it's the main verb of a sentence which governs the use of **in** — e.g. it is indispensable in _I don't **see** anything strange **in** washing dishes at 4 a.m._

Comment: @Mv Log: It is not indispensable there at all.  That pattern is very common in colloquial speech.  *I don't see anything strange, a guy going to a bar after work to have a beer.*

Comment: Not exactly, but the meaning becomes ambiguous: _...strange in washing_ vs _...strange while washing_.  _I don't see anything strange **in** going to a bar after work to have a beer._  _I don't see anything strange around going to a bar after work to have a beer._

Comment: "See anything strange in ..."    has nothing to do with the construction in the OP.